# Need help to create java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to make a GUI for following code but am unsure how to call that 
class.

I'm just trying to make a simple GUI design to throw.

Also can anyone tell how to stop "Tebak Angka Antara 1 dan 1000" from appearing every time I guessed the number?

the code:

```
public class TebakAngka {

    public static void AcakAngka (String [] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int AngkaAcak = rand.nextInt(1000);
        int Tebakan = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int tebakan;
        boolean win = false;

        while (win == false) {

        System.out.println("Tebak Angka Antara 1 dan 1000");
        tebakan = input.nextInt();
        Tebakan++;

        if (tebakan == AngkaAcak) {
            win = true;
        }
        else if (tebakan < AngkaAcak - 50) {
            System.out.println("Lebih Tinggi!");
        }
        else if (tebakan > AngkaAcak + 50){
            System.out.println("Lebih Rendah!");
        }
        else System.out.println("Sedikit lagi");
        }   

        System.out.println("Kamu Menang");
        System.out.println("Angkanya Adalah" + AngkaAcak);
        System.out.println("TebakanKe" + Tebakan);
    }
}
```

possible GUI ?

```
public class GUI {
private static JTextField textField;
private static JTextField textField_1;

public static void main(String args[]){
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Tebak Angka");
myFrame.setSize(400,300);
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
myFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
textField = new JTextField();
textField.setBounds(157, 156, 90, 20);
myFrame.getContentPane().add(textField);
textField.setColumns(10);
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Submit");
btnNewButton.setBounds(157, 187, 89, 23);
myFrame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
JTextArea txtrTextArea = new JTextArea();
txtrTextArea.setText("Input History and clues goes here");
txtrTextArea.setBounds(73, 25, 264, 101);
myFrame.getContentPane().add(txtrTextArea);
JLabel lblNumOfTries = new JLabel("Num of Tries");
lblNumOfTries.setBounds(10, 207, 60, 14);
myFrame.getContentPane().add(lblNumOfTries);
textField_1 = new JTextField();
textField_1.setBounds(80, 204, 22, 20);
myFrame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
textField_1.setColumns(10);
myFrame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Simple answer would be to try a GUI builder, like the ones freely available in Netbeans or Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of your question is pretty broad because the class (code) you provided isn't meant to be handled by GUI components like labels, buttons, and input dialogues. It will be difficult to answer it in any reasonable way, IMHO.

As far as the last part...

> Also can anyone tell how to stop "Tebak Angka Antara 1 dan 1000" from
>   appearing every time I guessed the number?

Yes, simply move `System.out.println("Tebak Angka Antara 1 dan 1000");` outisde the `while` loop you have just above it.

Instead of...

```
...
while (win == false) {
    System.out.println("Tebak Angka Antara 1 dan 1000");
    ...
```

you should...

```
...
System.out.println("Tebak Angka Antara 1 dan 1000");
while (win == false) { 
...
```

A little nit-pick would be `while(win == false)`. It's a bit redundant because `win` is already a boolean and evaluates directly. `while(!win)`, if `win = false;` initially is a bit cleaner.

Comment: this is actually my first time doing java swing, so i was thinking  to make a simple GUI where the input history and clue would go into a textpane and then a textfield for input and a button for submitting the input. but it isn't as  easy as it is in my mind. and so i've added a new class for the GUI, is it possible call the TebakAngka class into the GUI if the GUI looks like that ?